# How to show that $O(y)\ne 6?$

Tags: group-theory

Let in a group of $G$ order $6$ has an element $x$ of order $3.$ Choose $y\notin\left< x\right>.$ How to show that $O(y)\ne 6?$

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something - let $G=\mathbb{Z}_5$ and $x=2$ has order $3$, but $y=1 \not \in <2> = \{0,2,4\}$ has order $6$?

Comment: Huh? The cyclic group of order 6 has an element $x$ of order 3, and it has an element $y$ of order 6, not in the subgroup generated by $x$. So what you want to show, is false.

Comment: Let $y\neq e_G$ and the order of $y$ should divide $|G|=6=3\times 2$ so $|y|=3$ or $|y|=2$. Since $y\notin\langle x\rangle$ of order $3$, so $|y|=2$ or $|y|=6$. Now, why this poor $y$ cannot have the order $6$?

Comment: It holds for the *other* group of order $6$, which is $S_3$. But that is because there is no element of order $6$, so it holds in a kinda  vacuous way...

Comment: Perhaps this step occurs in the middle of a proof, and it has been assumed already that the group in question is not cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a concrete example. Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ be the additive group of integers modulo 6 and choose the elements $x=2$ and $y=5$. Then $\left<x\right>=\{0,2,4\}$, so $|x|=3$. But $y\notin\left<x\right>$ and $|y|=6$, which is a contradiction. Hence the statement is not possible to prove.